# Need to slide instead of fading out in jQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, slider

I've a very stupid function for sliding out images within a div.

The only problem is that fades in/out instead of sliding.

```
            var w    = $win.width();
            var x    = $(this).hasClass("stac-icon-scrollarrow-right") ? -w : w;
            var x2   = $(this).hasClass("stac-icon-scrollarrow-right") ? w : -w;
            var s;

            currentIndex = 0;
            function slide() {

                if ( currentIndex >= $('.slide img').length )
                  currentIndex = 0

                if ( currentIndex < 0 )
                  currentIndex = $('.slide img').length - 1

                $('.slide').fadeOut(500, function () {
                    $el = $('.slides img:eq('+currentIndex+')');

                    $('.slide').attr('src', $el.attr('src'));
                    $('.slide').fadeIn(500);
                });
            }

            currentIndex++;
            slide();
```

Comment: use slideUp() instead of fadeOut() and slideDown() instead of fadeIn()

Comment: Thank you for your answer, but it's not smooth and shows white space. I am hoping to slide left/right with immediate image appearing without any white space. Something like here http://www.slidesjs.com/

Comment: if you can create a demo at http://jsfiddle.net/ we can have a look... in order to make it work we need to know the html structure are well as the styles applied

Comment: This old question probably needed an [mcve] at the time, but appears to have been abandoned now. It is probably best closed.